# UIView take a screenshot when it is not visible

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a UIView that can be drawn like a finger paint application, but sometimes it is not visible. I want to be able to take a screenshot of it when it is not visible. Also, I want a screenshot where it is visible, but I don't want any subviews. I just want the UIView itself. This is the method I have tried:

```
func shapshot() -> UIImage? {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size)
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
        return nil
    }
    self.layer.render(in: context)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    if image == nil {
        return nil
    }

    return image
}

func snapshot() -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, self.isOpaque, UIScreen.main.scale)
    layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image!
}
```

Comment: your question is bit unclear, anyways you can take the screenshot of a view in this case the whole components are the part of that view will be visible in that screenshot ..

Answer (score 3):

To get view rendered as `UIImage`, you could introduce a very simple protocol and extend `UIView` with it.

```swift
protocol Renderable {
    var render: UIImage { get }
}

extension UIView: Renderable {
    var render: UIImage {
        UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds).image { context in
            layer.render(in: context.cgContext)
        }
    }
}
```

and now it's super easy to get the image of **any** view

```swift
let image: UIImage = someView.render
```

then if you plan to share it or save it, you probably want to convert it to `Data`

```swift
let data: Data? = image.pngData()
```

I am not sure what you mean with the "when it is not visible" but this should work as long as the view is in the view hierarchy and it's properly laid out. I have been using this method in many apps for sharing stuff and it never failed me.

And of course there is no need for a protocol, feel free to use only the `render` computed property. It's just a matter of preference.

---

Documentation:
[UIGraphicsImageRenderer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigraphicsimagerenderer),  [image(actions:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigraphicsimagerenderer/1649230-image)